# Trying to dynamically return function method wrapper based on method key

Tags: typescript

Below I am trying to pass 'beta' to `.example` and have proper typing.
I'm getting the error below.

```
class Letters {
    alpha (a: string): string {
        return a
    }

    beta (b: number): number {
        return b
    }

    example <T extends 'alpha' | 'beta'> (i: T) {
        return (param: Parameters<Letters[T]>[0]): ReturnType<Letters[T]> => {
            return this[i](param)
        }
    }
}

(new Letters()).example('beta')(4)
```

> (parameter) param: Parameters[0] Argument of type
>
> 'Parameters[0]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>
> 'never'.   Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)